# How does diplomatic immunity work in the case of a diplomat being a dual citizen of both the host and guest nations?

Tags: international-relations, taxes, embassy, diplomatic-immunity

How would the legal precedence work, and have there ever been any such cases?

For example, let's say that someone was born in the USA (and has citizenship by birthright), but their family moved to Mexico when they were an infant. They grew up to become a Mexican diplomat, and were sent to the United States (is this possible?).

Now they are a dual citizen living in the country of their other citizenship, having diplomatic immunity while still being bound by the host nation's laws.

Which one takes priority?

For example, the IRS (as it's been known to do over the last 10 years) might start hassling them to backpay all of the taxes they "owe" for all the money they ever earned in their adult life in MX; could the diplomat claim diplomatic immunity in this case?

*Side question:* What if we are not dealing with a diplomat, but let's say a politician on a government visit (let's say they are visiting the White House). If this politician is a dual citizen, and the IRS finds out, could they issue an arrest order? Would this order be carried out by the White House security staff?

Comment: There's an even simpler example for the former: the [United States ambassador to the United Nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ambassadors_of_the_United_States_to_the_United_Nations) is a US citizen - and is based in New York.

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff a diplomat is not immune from the jurisdiction of the sending state; in this case the sending state would be the US.
A more pertinent example would be a dual US-other citizen representing the other country at the UN.  But UN diplomats' privileges and immunities are slightly different from "regular" diplomats; they're governed by the UN charter and, in New York, by the UN Headquarters Agreement.

Comment: for 'ordinary' people (incomes up to about fourth quintile) their _earned_ income would be excluded from US tax, so IRS wouldn't try to go after that; they might go after tax on _unearned_ income like investments especially if there are any that get special breaks in MX (or wherever) but not US. And they could go after failure to _report_ foreign _assets_ (which is not a tax but is enforced by IRS). Compare https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/113238/us-capital-gains-tax-for-us-citizens-living-in-ireland-on-us-brokerage-stock-sal (disclosure: my answer)

Answer (score 18):

In general, diplomats are not supposed to be nationals of the receiving state, though the receiving state may elect to consent to the appointment of one of its nationals (Article 8 of the Vienna convention).

Article 38 of the Vienna convention provides:

> 1. Except insofar as additional privileges and immunities may be granted by the receiving State, a
>    diplomatic agent who is a national of or permanently resident in that State shall enjoy only immunity
>    from jurisdiction, and inviolability, in respect of official acts performed in the exercise of his functions.
> 2. Other members of the staff of the mission and private servants who are nationals of or
>    permanently resident in the receiving State shall enjoy privileges and immunities only to the extent
>    admitted by the receiving State. However, the receiving State must exercise its jurisdiction over those
>    persons in such a manner as not to interfere unduly with the performance of the functions of the mission.

So the IRS action would likely not be blocked by immunity, since it concerns personal income.

Politicians on official visits are generally treated like diplomats.

Regarding the suggestion that Boris Johnson is a pertinent example, he is not, because his tax issues were resolved before he became foreign secretary.  But considering the case of a diplomat who *isn't* a US citizen but nonetheless owes something to the IRS might be instructive.  Such a person could be the subject of a court judgement that would be unenforceable by a US court while the diplomat is accredited to the US, but it would be enforceable after the diplomat's diplomatic status ends.  A US citizen's lack of diplomatic immunity only makes the judgement enforceable earlier.

Comment: You don't have to make the IRS bit hypothetical.  Boris Johnson gave up his US citizenship, in 2017, while serving as a foreign secretary of the UK specifically because the IRS wanted him to pay too much tax on a British property (by his own admission).  As a *foreign secretary* of the UK, he was the chief diplomatic officer of a state other than the US.

Comment: @wrod he also paid the tax bill.  Renouncing US citizenship did not excuse him from it.  Furthermore, his case does not serve as an example showing whether a diplomat in such circumstances would be subject to the jurisdiction of a court because no court ever sought to impose its jurisdiction on him ... because he paid the tax ... before he became foreign secretary.

Comment: I wonder how this applies to heads of state, at least in theory (in practice I assume they’re given immunity).

Comment: @cpast head of state immunity seems to be somewhat tied up in sovereign immunity (more so, of course, when the head of state is a sovereign), and, since there's no convention governing it, it falls into "customary international law" or something like that.  I suppose that this means that it's more inconsistent from one country to the next.  The late king of Thailand was a US citizen from birth; nobody ever made any assertions one way or the other about whether his accession to the throne resulted in loss of US citizenship.

Comment: @phoog: In other news, in line to the UK throne (not next in line child of next in line) is a child still accounted a US citizen because it's not possible to drop citizenship before 18. And the IRS has requested tax information from the British crown. You can see how that will go.

Comment: @Joshua what are you talking about, or rather whom?  Harry and Meghan live in the US, so their (and their children's) worldwide income is taxable in the US regardless of their citizenship.  (Megan's and the children's worldwide income is also taxable in the US regardless of residence because they are US citizens.) That wouldn't expose any other members of the British royal family to US taxation, much less the crown.  And none of them are diplomats.

Comment: @phoog re: "nobody ever made assertions one way or the other..."  He did. He had said that continued to consider himself a US citizen.

Comment: @phoog Johnson recognized the IRS' authority to impose the tax.  Again, that's why he relinquished the citizenship.  Obviously it would be undiplomatic to allow the situation to escalate to the point of IRS asking for UK to take measures to force the pay of the tax if he challenged it.  So it would be bad form for him, as a chief diplomatic officer, to allow it to escalate to that point.  It's an excellent example of where the boundaries are drawn.

Comment: @wrod you can say that, but it doesn't make it true.  Can you point to some evidence that he ever made such a statement (or filed an income tax return)?  Of course not.  Regarding Johnson, the IRS would never have sought to force him to pay the tax while he was chief diplomatic officer because he had already paid it.  You're creating controversy where none exists.  Johnson also said that he was giving up his US citizenship to demonstrate loyalty to the UK, not for tax reasons, but that was probably a lie so he wouldn't be inadmissible to the US.

Comment: @wrod back to Bhumibol, the interpretation of the US constitution that would have allowed him to retain US citizenship did not arise until the late 1960s, two decades after he ascended the throne.  He could have tried to assert US citizenship after that point, but not before.  And he never did.

Comment: @phoog can I? if i look for it, yes.  I have read it before (it was a direct quite of Johnson saying it).  Unless you were talking about the Bhumibol... I"ve read that direct statement, too. But (if I am going to be honest) you are a little too hostile for me to indulge your curiosity.  I tried to be supportive by saying what a good answer you had and how it could be made even better.  Instead of a "thank you" I got... whatever this was.  So... well, have a great day! And enjoy the rest of the interwebs.  BTW, I was one of the 1st to upvote this answer.  You are welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138391/discussion-between-phoog-and-wrod).